# how to make opacity of div lower than the over layered iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I want to display sign up form where page is grayed out and the iframe containing the form appear in the middle as follows:

code:

```
<div id="cover5">
    <iframe name="warning" src="SignIn.php" id="warning" style="position: relative; height: 250px;">
     </iframe>
</div>
```

css:

```
#cover5 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    text-align:center;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#warning {
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: 150px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:fit-content;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    border: 5px solid #003366;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

i want the opacity of the cover(div) to be low (background is blured) while the iframe shouldn't be blured, the problem is when i change the opacity of the div, the opacity of the iframe changes as well, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Huangism mentioned, you can leave the #cover5 style the way it is, remove the  outside the #cover5 div and apply absolute positioning to the iframe to center it on the screen.

Specifically, to the

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
```

Just make sure that you offset your margins by HALF of the container's width and height, in this case:

```
margin: -125px 0 0 -300px; /* The height is 250px and the width is 600px */
```

And your markup would look like this:

```
<div id="cover5"></div>

<iframe name="warning" src="SignIn.php" id="warning" style="position: relative; height: 250px;"></iframe>
```

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/VxntD/

Answer (score 1):

Take the iframe out of the cover5 and position it with absolute. You do not need t touch the opacity of iframe in this case

Answer (score 1):

Because your iframe is embedded in cover5, it is affected by cover5’s opacity.  And from what I can tell, there is no way around this.  I’ve tried setting z-indexs and other display settings, but nothing works.

However, because your cover5 div is absolutely positioned, and your warning is not, change your markup to this, which should solve your problem;

```
<div id="cover5"></div>
<iframe name="warning" src="SignIn.php" id="warning" style="position: relative; height: 250px;"></iframe>
```

Also, `opacity` is not supported cross browser, so your css should include these other rules;

```
-khtml-opacity: .50;
-moz-opacity: .50;
-ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=50)”;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
opacity:.50;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to have opacity on a parent and not a child is NOT to use opacity and use **alpha channel** instead (RGBa).

Warning: RGBa is not supported on older browsers.

```
background-color:rgba(128,128,128,.5);
```

See: http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/03/29/rgba-vs-opacity-the-difference-explained/

Answer (score 0):

A jquery implementation would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cover5').animate({opacity: 0.5},1000); // which changes opacity smoothly
});
```

--

See working demo of your code with the opacity animated effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/teFYa/